# Просмотр XML файла

Tags: c#, xml

Как через `OpenFileDialog` открыть XML файл и просмотреть его в `textbox` или `listbox`?
То есть Вы меня поняли, через нажатие кнопки, открываем XML документ и просматриваем его.
Спасибо! :)

Comment: А обычный текстовый документ пробовали открывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml";
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(fileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой контрол [WebBrouser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx). Можно использовать его. А также можно просто открыть XML файл как текстовый документ и на форме вывести его в [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)